# What is the difference between `踢足球` and `踢球`?

Tags: word-choice, word

I've read the following two sentences today:

```
我以前在这里踢足球
现在我在踢球
```

However, what is the difference between the `踢足球` and `踢球`? I think both means `playing soccer`, but is there any difference?

Comment: I feel a bit confused about the first sentence in the example. How can someone play soccer in a car? I guess what the person meant was that he/she was playing a soccer-themed video game while inside a car.

Comment: second "踢球"
maybe meaning his job is professional soccer player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have the same meaning on usual---playing football. For `踢球`'s `球` ,it is the football in general. If we must point out the difference,there is a tiny difference merely to `踢足球` is a specific(or definite) statement, that is to say, it is more concrete. 
When you make sentence or want to express play football, both of them are ok.:)

Comment: Thanks. Then even if I use `踢球`, can the people always grasp it is about soccer? And which is more popular? As to the title, sorry, that's a typo.

Comment: Yeah,in china people would always(though not a hundred percent but ninety-nine percent of people would) grasp it about soccer.^_^ Eh...I think 踢球 is more popular, most cause of there is no more other balls can play,so 球 is mean to be 足球. And 踢球 is more simple and abridged . It's ok,and I am glad to help you get rid of doubt.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put it like this. On a character-by-character basis, `踢球` is `kick-ball`. Therefore, `踢球` should basically mean `play a ball game where feet are used`. How many such games do you know? I, for one, only know football. That is why `踢球` will be interpreted as football. To be more specific, you add the `足`. Then, `踢` is taken as `play`, and `足球` is `foot-ball`. Similarly, I would guess `打球` is a general terms for hand-played ball games, literally `hit-ball`. Adding a character (syllable) just before `球` (e.g. `篮` for `basketball` or `排` for `volleyball`) specifies what `ball` you are `hit`ting. Then again, I'm not a native, so these suggestions need to be taken with a spoon of rice.

Answer (score 0):

nay guys… 踢球can be an activity of kicking any kind of balls (well?) but 踢足球is specified as playing soccer(or football, depending on if u r a british or 'murican)